# Infinispan Interceptor Configuration?

Tags: java, caching, interceptor, infinispan

In infinispan server 6.0.0.CR1 if i want to add some filters or interceptors where should i add them and is there a better documentation that can guide me through. I basically want to intercept the REST call to grab the application ID and add some restriction's while accessing the  named caches.

Custom Interceptors section in the UserGuide make more sense for Embedded Cache but with cache server how cani configure the interceptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deploy user code to Infinispan server, which is why neither interceptors nor listeners can be plugged into remote caches currently. If you have a web proxy, you could maybe do the restrictions there.

Comment: Hi Galder Do you know of any open source modules( web proxy ) that can serve my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As Galder said, the server configuration does not allow for easily inserting a custom interceptor in the chain. We have plans on how to allow this in an easy, deployable fashion, but until then this requires patching the infinispan subsystem.

Comment: Hi when you say patching the subsystems , so are there any subsystems available out there that can allow binding interceptors that i can add to infiispan installation?